# What does InnoDB stand for?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I was comparing [MyISAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM) with [InnoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB). I found out that ISAM is acronym of *Indexed Sequential Access Method*. what about InnoDB, what does it stand for?

Comment: From wikipedia: *"InnoDB became a product of Oracle Corporation after its acquisition of Innobase Oy in October 2005."*.  *"Inno"* is commonly found in "innovation". I don't think this is a question for SO, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the name of a product, not about programing

Comment: from my point of view, when programming an application, i need to know what i'm using, what is the thing that i use. and i think a lot of libraries that we use in our apps are also a product. well, there is a tag for MS visual studio in stackoverflow questions, obviously MSVC is a product of a company... .

Comment: @hmojtaba so as the final answer, InnoDB stand for something like "Innovated Database" or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB is a storage engine for MySQL. MySQL 5.5 and later use it by default. It provides the standard ACID-compliant transaction features, along with foreign key support (Declarative Referential Integrity). It is included as standard in most binaries distributed by MySQL AB, the exception being some OEM versions.
InnoDB became a product of Oracle Corporation after its acquisition of Innobase Oy in October 2005.The software is dual licensed; it is distributed under the GNU General Public License, but can also be licensed to parties wishing to combine InnoDB in proprietary software.